# In Corda, can the network operator control the contract sandbox whitelist?

Tags: corda

My understanding is that Corda uses a whitelist to control which Java libraries can be used as part of contract verification. This ensures that contract execution is deterministic.

Is there any way to customise this whitelist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Corda V3, the deterministic sandbox for contract execution has not yet been implemented.

Ultimately, contracts executing in the sandbox will only have access to a subset of the Java standard libraries. However, the mechanism by which Corda will restrict access to other libraries - and whether nodes or network operators will be able to customise this set of available libraries - has not yet been determined.